# Set up a regexp - R

Tags: r, regex

I am struggling with regexp in R. I just want to check if a string contains ONLY alphanumeric or any of these symbols `?._-#$`

I am  trying with the following to find strings that contain any other symbol:

```
grepl("[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|\\?|\\$|\\-|\\_|\\#]",xx)
```

I made a check with `xx = "Ra?a"` and it returns TRUE. Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `grepl` with a single character class:

```r
x <- c("Hello", "Hello!")
grepl("^[A-Za-z0-9?._#$-]+$", x)

[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried so, but with more symbols I get an error: `Error in grepl("^[A-Za-z0-9?!,._-+#$&%=.]+$", xx) : 
  invalid regular expression '^[A-Za-z0-9?!,._-+#$&%=.]+$', reason 'Invalid character range'
In addition: Warning message:
In grepl("^[A-Za-z0-9?!,._-+#$&%=.]+$", xx) :
  TRE pattern compilation error 'Invalid character range'`

Comment: Reload your page.

Comment: Well ... `x <- c("Hell@", "Hello!")
grepl("^[A-Za-z0-9?._#$-]+$", x) returns FALSE FALSE`

Comment: aha! so by adding +$, somehow now it returns TRUE if  all characters are in the :allowed" list?